# Removing the return tag from response xml in axis2 webservice

Tags: web-services, apache-axis

In all my xml web services, I always get the response things embedded inside the <ns:response> tag. I don't want my response to come inside <ns:return>, rather directly inside the main tag. I have seen such a response. I want my web service to return the output in the same way.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. I just had to set the message receiver to the generated message receiver (generated by wsdl2java). If the message receiver is the default ones e.g. the RPCMessageReceiver, then the response will be embedded in <return> tag. If we set the message receiver to our custom message receiver (generated message receiver ) then the response won't come within <return> tag.