# how to remove the <return> tag from response xml in axis2 Wizard generated bottom up webservice

Tags: eclipse, apache-axis

I see [Surya's reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241848/removing-the-return-tag-from-response-xml-in-axis2-webservice) as below for the above query. It seems it's pretty similar to the problem that I'm trying to resolve; however, I could not get it perhaps because of my lack of knowledge in this specific area.

I have generated my service using `Wizard, Axis2, Tomcat7 and Eclipse - Java EE`. My service is a bottom up Java service and I cannot understand how I can get rid of that tag.

Please note I'm not using explicitly to generate any Java class using `wsdl2java`, my entire project is just Wizard based.

Any assistance Surya, or others would be very much appreciated.

thanks in advance

Surya's explanation below which I'm requesting for elaboration:

> I got it. I just had to set the message receiver to the generated
>   message receiver (generated by wsdl2java). If the message receiver is
>   the default ones e.g. the RPCMessageReceiver, then the response will
>   be embedded in  tag. If we set the message receiver to our
>   custom message receiver (generated message receiver ) then the
>   response won't come within  tag.

Answer (score 0):

In the Services.xml you may be having the message receiver as

```
<messageReceiver class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver" mep="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl/in-only"/>
        <messageReceiver class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver" mep="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl/in-out"/>
```

at the service level. if you want your own message receiver as mentioned by Surya you can change it here. If you want to further customize it to have separate message receiver at your operation level you can define it as below

```
 <operation name=doSmt>
      <messageReceiver class="org.apache.axis2.MyMessageReceiver"/>
 </operation>
```